# Search customer by any of the optional field like firstname, address etc - performance issue

Tags: oracle, spring-data-jpa, querydsl

How to deal with a performance issue in searching from database as mentioned below:

In the app i am working on , has a `searchCustomer` functionality where api will return the list of customers based on the search criteria. The search request will be like this:

```
 <Search>
               <name>
                  <firstName>fname</firstName>
                  <lastName>lname</lastName>
               </name>
               <address>
                  <addressLine1>address1</addressLine1>
                  <postalCode>679122</postalCode>
                  <city>testcity</city>
                  <countryCode>US</countryCode>
               </address>
            <id>
            <Customerid>1234<customerid>
    <Search>
    <Search>
               <name>
                  <firstName>fname</firstName>
                  <lastName>lname</lastName>
               </name>
               <address>
                  <addressLine1>address1</addressLine1>
                  <postalCode>679122</postalCode>
                  <city>testcity</city>
                  <countryCode>US</countryCode>
               </address>
            <id>
            <Customerid>1234<customerid>
    <Search>
```

In this request its not necessary to mention all the fields, any one of the field is enough.

If we could find a list of customers based on that given field we will return those customers.

How current system work is, process the list of items one by one, create a predicate using `querydsl` then fetch the data using `springdata` `findall` method.

Since the request list can have hundreds of items, processing is too slow and is taking more than a minute to get the response.

What is the right approach to do this kind of search?

Comment: The right approach is to access and filter the data in the database using SQL, possibly with the help of appropriate indexes. In order to do that, you have to write the appropriate SELECT statement. What logic is followed to interpret that search input? Where are the ANDs and where are the ORs? What is the underlying data model?

Comment: By the way, your input XML has several errors. Why do you have the same "Search" element with the same data twice?

Comment: @StewAshton That search element can be repeating. Ofcourse it wont be same data. But there is no restriction in the request so that users cant request for same data twice in the same request. In short: Api is not to lookup for single customer but it can lookup many customers in the same request

Comment: OK, but then your XML doesn't parse because it doesn't have a root element. Are you saying the input doesn't have to be well-formed XML?

Comment: @StewAshton I copied a part of my soap request. Couldnt copy the full request because of security reason, and for conveying the problem that isn't required either i guess.

Comment: By the way, my question about the search **logic** is still open.